# Is there a way to make a NextJS Image component fill its parent container width-wise and respond with a height to preserve its dimensions?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

I would like to have two Next JS image components side-by-side and fill the screen width-wise (with a bit of padding, of course) but have a responsive height to preserve the images' dimensions.

Here is my code:

```
<div className='flex flex-row p-4 border w-full justify-center'>

            <div className='w-1/2 h-screen border relative'>
                <Image src="{src}" layout='fill' />
            </div>

            <div className='w-1/2 h-screen border relative'>
                <Image src="{src}" layout='fill' />
            </div>
 </div>
```

Obviously, specifying a width and height on the parent div and fill on the image will not preserve its dimensions, so my instinct was to use h-max instead to set a width and have it fill the image height, but on screen it is empty since there is nothing to fill...

Answer (score 0):

One of the things/hacks you can use is to wrap the `<Image>` with a `div` and add classes to this div (like `h` or `w`) and put the layout of the image responsive i.e.`layout=responsive`. This will allow the images to be volatile with changing dimensions.